# MS Access VBA Pass Through Query Connection Error when using Excel

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I can connect to Oracle with a Passthrough query using ODBC to Oracle but the issue I have is because I have multiple databases that all use the same connections I want to store my credentials for the servers in an Excel encrypted file so nobody can see my passwords and only need to update in one place instead of every database but when I try and connect with my passthrough it doesnt work but does if I manually declare them in vba.

The Error Message is 3151 - ODBC - connection to '{Oracle in OraClientName}Server' failed

This is my code and dont know why it doesnt work? I tried with DSN and its the same result?

```
Function MyConnection()
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MY_TRANS"
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0 

'''''GET EXCEL LOGIN DETAILS
Dim xlsApp
Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim WkBk As Excel.WorkBook
Set WkBk = xlsApp.WorkBooks.Open(FileName:="FILE LOCATION.xlsx", Password:="MYPASSWORD")

Dim LOGONNAME As String
Dim PWD As String

LOGONNAME = WkBk.Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value
PWD = WkBk.Sheets(1).Range("D3").Value

If Not (xlsApp Is Nothing) Then xlsApp.Quit
'end excel stuff
xlsApp.Quit
Set xlsApp = Nothing

'THIS WORKS IF I UNCOMMENT
'LOGONNAME = "MYNAME"
'PWD = "PASSWORD"


Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ExtData As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
Set ExtData = db.CreateQueryDef("MY_TRANS")

ServerName = "MYSERVER"
ExtData.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in OraClientName};Server=" & ServerName & ";DBQ=DBQNAME;UID=" & LOGONNAME & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ""

ExtData.SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "MY_TRANS"
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "MY_TRANS"
 
ExtData.Close
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

END FUNCTION
```

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). You could do `Debug.Print LOGONNAME, (LOGONNAME = "MYNAME")` after reading it from Excel - obviously that doesn't work like you expect it to.

Comment: I just tried this and the PWD shows as false? I have now retyped in the Excel and now it works, Thank you for this :)

Answer (score 0):

@Andre Your Comment fixed the issue The Answer is if you get false after typing Debug.Print LOGONNAME, (LOGONNAME = "MYNAME") and doing the same for the password then you will need to go into the excel and check the details are the same or retype and check again. This fixed the issue for me.